# I need to use this array in objective-c. How do I declare it as an explicit array in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

```
int8_t aLawCompressTable[64] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3, 
        4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, 
        5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5, 
        5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5, 
        6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6, 
        6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6, 
        6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6, 
        6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7, 
        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7 };
```

I have this data from some java code and need to use it in my objective-c class.

Comment: so what's your problem? use it as it is

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've been trying this declaration in the wrong place, that's why it didn't work. Sorry for posting it here for no reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is "don't do that". You should be using it as a C array in its current form. The only reason that a-law compression uses a lookup table is for speed - something you'll lose by turning it into an NSArray.

However, in answer to your question:

Here's a single-dimensional array

```
NSArray *a = @[ @(1), @2, @3 ];
```

Use @[] for an array, and @(1) (or just @) for an NSNumber (you can't put a primitive type in an NSArray).

You can also do dictionaries with @{}

```
NSDictionary *b = @{ @1: @2,  @3: @4};
```

Finally, you can nest these as many times as you like:

Here's a multi-dimensional array

```
NSArray *a = @[ 
               @[ @1, @1 ],
               @[ @2, @2 ] ];
```

Comment: you can do `@1`, `@2`

Comment: Ta, had forgotten that.

Comment: the questioner's array is not multidimensional

Comment: I know. It's a trivial question, and I decided to demonstrate a slightly more complex case to show that it works.